# How can a server certificate be valid when there's a hostname/issued to mistmatch?

Tags: tls, certificates

i was wondering - i was surprised to check out a specific site's certificate and see that the hostname is not equal to the issued to parameter - the certificate is valid.

The example is here: https://www.cyberark.com

[image: Different issued to]

How is it possible? ssl762713.cloudflaressl.com is definitly not Cyberark.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cyberark.com is in SAN (subject alternative name) of that certificate